# Batch file issue (filenames with long file extension)

Tags: batch-file, wildcard, filenames, short-filenames

Recently I have written a simple BAT file to delete all unnecessary *.RES files from the current directory and its sub-directories:

```
del /S  "*.res"
```

But it deleted all *.RESX files in addition too (ooh, my luckless C# projects ...).

I understand that it converted all filenames to DOS 8.3 format before, so any file like "*Resources.resx*" will have DOS 8.3 filename "*resour~1.res*", so it will match the pattern "*.res" unfortunately.

**Question**: is there simple way to force the batch file to consider the **complete** filenames, **not 8.3** filenames?

At least to 'say' that the length of file extension should be 3 characters exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `dir` in cmd.exe uses the [`FindFirstFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilew) API due to legacy issues. That API [matches both long and 8.3 names](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=34883), hence [*.res and *.resx would be the same](https://superuser.com/q/238900/241386)

The simplest solution is to use powershell

```powershell
Get-ChildItem *.res -Recurse | Remove-Item
```

It can be called from cmd like this (here I replaced the cmdlets with their common aliases):

```bat
powershell -C "ls *.res -r | rm"
```

The pure batch solution would be more cumbersome

```bat
for /f "usebackq delims=|" %%f in (`dir /s /b ^| findstr /i /v /r "\.res.$"`) do del %%f
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You helped me a lot. (I'll include 2nd row into my old bat file).

Comment: also possible: `...^| findstr /ir "\.res$" ...`